# How to disable automatic namespace resolution in Intellisense for C# (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, autocomplete, intellisense, fully-qualified-naming

How can I disable automatic namespace resolution in Intellisense for C# (Visual Studio 2010)?

This might sound strange but I need to have the fully qualified names show up as follows:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form form = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();
```

Instead of:

```
Form form = new Form();
```

I could not find similar questions. Is this possible in VS2010?

**UPDATE**: I am aware about readability issues and when sharing code, qualified can be stripped easily. It is just a matter of preference in writing code that way.

Comment: This really appears to be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What is actually solved by this?  In other words, you believe that by solving this problem it will solve some other problem (of which you have not asked).

Comment: what is the purpose? This will make your code readability very poor.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: No ulterior motives. I am used to reading code with fully qualified namespaces for a decade now and find it annoying to have to type them out.

Comment: @ElYusubov: The code I write is mostly for myself and when sending it off, tools like ReSharper can toggle between fully qualified and relative with a click of a button.

Comment: And why the down vote? Most people may not be comfortable doing it that way but that does not make this a bad question.

Comment: This also sounds to me like an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the fully qualified names **will** show up if you start typing the namespaces.

So start by typing `System`, and you'll see a list of symbols in the `System` namespace.  and you can continue on like that until you have `System.Windows.Forms.Form`

If you really really badly want intellisence to stop giving you stop resolving namespaces, than you can just delete all the `using` statements at the top of your file, and then paste them back in when you're done.  I wouldn't do this if I were you, but then again, I wouldn't want to stop resolving namespaces either.

Comment: That only happens if the name you type is not within the namespace hierarchy of the class you type in. It should also not be in `using` statements of course.

Comment: @RaheelKhan  I think you misunderstood.  Don't start with typing "Form" start with typing "System"

Comment: That does not work for me without having to type it out until I reach "Form". That is annoying.

Comment: @RaheelKhan with intellisence you just have to type as far as `Sy` and then `System` will be probably be highlighted, in which case you can just press the `.` key and continue with `Windows`

Comment: If you remove the using namespaces  and type Form, the F should be underlined (works with all classes).  In cases where the first letter is underlined of any class that is contained in a reference but not in a using clause, you can press Ctrl+. (Ctrl+Period) and it will give you the option to EITHER; add a using statement, or prefix form with the namespace containing the class.